# download file on a specific folder in jsp

Tags: jsp, download, directory

I have already try and tested downloading any file from server to client side PC using JSP

But what i am concerning is how to download it a specific folder, below are my current code:

```
 <%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.OutputStream"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.BufferedOutputStream"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.BufferedInputStream"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.File"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.FileWriter"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>

<%  
    String filename = "K:\\gcache/rispacs.net/267/1.2.392.200036.9125.9.0.319792973.175747576.2790676870.dcm";
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename=\"test.dcm\"";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
    File fileToDownload = new File(filename);
    System.out.print("1");

    InputStream ins = null;
    ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();  

    int name =  filename.lastIndexOf("/");
    String format = filename.substring(name);

    try {
        ins = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToDownload));

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\dcmsyst/cache/"+format);
        int ch;
        while ((ch = ins.read()) != -1) {
        outs.print((char) ch);
        }



    }
    finally {
    if (ins != null) ins.close(); // very important
    }

    outs.flush();
    outs.close();
    ins.close();    
%>
```

It is now running, but the file that was downloaded to the specified folder was 0KB.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working. You can try

```
 response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+fileName);
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileObject+"\\"+fileName);
 FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(paths);
 int i;
 while((i=fileInputStream.read())!=-1)
 {
   out.write(i);
 }
 fileInputStream.close(); 
 out.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

To download a file in java you have to write the the content to the response, in your code you are just writing in to another folder in the server. Since the content type is set to `application/octet-stream` you are getting a empty file. To download a file you have to do the following

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
```

---

> But what i am concerning is how to download it a specific folder

This is browser settings cannot be done at the server side.

Comment: Actually Sir with the code above, i can already downloaded it to a specific folder, its just that it it 0kb file

Comment: What you are doing is coping `K:\\gcache/rispacs.net/267/1.2.392.200036.9125.9.0.319792973.175747576.2790676870.dcm` file to `C:\\dcmsyst/cache/` folder its not file download it's coping.